# Accessing elements created by a hosted JS script

Tags: javascript, html

Our company has a donation form created by a third party (Online Express/Blackbaud). To put the form on our website, we copy the embed code given to us

```
<div id="bbox-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
       window.bboxInit = function () {
           bbox.showForm('b92c013e-b098-45db-bed4-3539674ff251');
       };
       (function () {
           var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
           e.src = 'https://bbox.blackbaudhosting.com/webforms/bbox-min.js';
           document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(e);
       } ());
</script>
```

and paste it in the page's content section.

I'd like to set the value of one of the inputs on the form, but using document.getElementById() returns a null object. However, I know for a fact that the object does exist because I copied the ID of the object from the developer inspection window. What reason would there be for getElementById() failing to retrieve an object that definitely exists? And what way is there for me to access the element?

Thanks for any advice.

Full code:

```
<div id="bbox-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
       window.bboxInit = function () {
           bbox.showForm('b92c013e-b098-45db-bed4-3539674ff251');
       };
       (function () {
           var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
           e.src = 'https://bbox.blackbaudhosting.com/webforms/bbox-min.js';
           document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(e);
           
       } ());
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 display = window.open("", "", popup=true);
 f1 = document.getElementById('bboxdonation_giftattributes_ctl00_txtAttrib');
 display.document.write(f1); // writes "null"
</script>
```

[Proof that object is on page with ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1SB3.png)

Comment: Is that within an iframe? If so, you can't access content within the iframe. You'll have to check with the service to see if they offer an option for something like that.

Comment: @asportnoy You would be correct. I searched the actual HTML on the page and the form itself is located in an iframe. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

When fetching an element from the DOM via `getElementById()`, you need to ensure whatever script you imported is being loaded **after** the document loads. You can do this by adding the `defer` atrribute to your script tag, which means it'll load after the body has completed loading regardless of the location of the script in code, i.e.

```html
<script defer type="text/javascript">
    // ...
</script>
```

You can paste a regular script tag anywhere in the code, but it will only be able to access elements prior to that script tag. By adding defer, you will be able to access all content loaded on the page once the script loads.